# MonoDevelop in mac, ResourceManager can not read value from resource file

Tags: c#, macos, monodevelop

We meet one issue for loading Mac resource with Xamarin. We have one resource
file named Resource1.resx. It failed when loading one string from this resource
file with below code. Please refer attachment sample to create this issue.
Could you please give some advice to load resource?

If you need any more information, please let me know that. Please check the
codes(in MainWindows.cs) as follow:

```
partial void loadResourceButtonClicked(MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject sender){
    try{
        var b = Resources1.ResourceManager;
        var name = b.GetString("Name1");
        resultLabel.StringValue = name;
    }
    catch {
        resultLabel.StringValue = "Resource load failed.";
    }
}
```

PS.We have attached [the test project](https://ap.thinkgeo.com:5001/fbsharing/e9VdsrrM), please have a check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'hidden' exception:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "MacResourceTest.Resources1.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "MacResourceTest" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

The key phase in that exception message is '**Make sure XXXX was correctly embedded or linked into assembly**'.

A quick look at your project and the `.resx` file is flagged incorrectly as a *Build Action* of `BundleResource`. OSX/iOS BundleResource's are typically used for binary, xml, text, etc.. but NOT `.resx` files as they originate via the `System.Resources.ResourceManager` and need to be added to the CIL assembly in a specific way (mainly due to culture localization).

1) Flag `.resx` files as a `Build Action` of `EmbeddedResource`

2) If your going to 'hide' exceptions and provide a 'user friendly' message, include the actual exception messages in Console debugging messaging, logging, somewhere, etc...

3) In posting questions to StackOverflow, please post the actual exception message / call stack.